# Achieving better performance with Spring Cache Abstraction

Tags: spring, spring-cache

I came across an article at http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/01/cacheable-overhead-in-spring.html that indicates that Spring Cache abstraction introduces overheads compared to a custom caching solution. Is there any implementation of the spring cache abstraction that is as close to a simple custom implementation as possible?

In my use case, I do not need eviction or size restriction on the cache. I do need expiration. Does the choice of a CacheManager make a difference to the performance of the spring cache abstraction? Will I get better performance with SimpleCacheManager compared to GuavaCacheManager?

Regards,
Yash

Answer (score 2):

> Does the choice of a CacheManager make a difference to the performance
>   of the spring cache abstraction ? Will I get better performance with
>   SimpleCacheManager compared to GuavaCacheManager ?

I don't think anyone can straight away give answers to your questions (in fact any performance related questions) without running the performance tests on your application code base.

Spring `CacheManager` is an abstraction layer provided to loose couple the applications with the cache vendors, which is a very good feature, otherwise you will end up with a vendor lock.

Now, coming to the performance, it all depends upon your application non-functional requirements (response times, etc.), you need to benchmark and compare the results to pick the best one.

Here, Spring `CacheManager` comes with a big advantage as you don't need to modify/rewrite your code to test with a different vendor as you need to just change the property files and performance test to compare and pick the best option.